# How To Use Tapjoy In An Android Webview?

Tags: android, webview, google-play, tapjoy

Currently I have an app with a virtual currency. I want to be able to use the currency to make money with Tapjoy.

**Problem**: My app simply loads a webview/web page/website. I want to be able to embed the Tapjoy api within my website (ie: html) not the android app itself.

Is this possible? If so how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of letting your webview occupy the entire screen, leave margin of 10 dip at the bottom
of the layout for your button saying 'Get Coins'. Let your webview occupy the remaining part of the layout.